# Attempt to index local 'button' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm walking through the following tutorial 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5Oz72MO4JI

but for some reason i'm getting the error `Attempt to index local 'button' (a nil value)`
I've rechecked everything in my code, and it seams correct like in the video

the full error:

```
ui.lua:130 Attempt to index local 'button' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
[C]:?

ui.lua:130 in function 'newButton'
```

code:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- main.lua
--
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
local ui = require("ui")
local background = display.newImage("background.jpg")
local gear = display.newImage("gear.png")
local gear2 = display.newImage("gear.png")

gear.x = display.stageWidth / 2 + 26
gear.y = display.stageHeight / 2 - 50
gear2.x = display.stageWidth * .63
gear2.y = display.stageHeight * .60

local rotateAmount = 1

local function animate( event )
    gear.rotation = gear.rotation + rotateAmount
    gear2.rotation = gear2.rotation - rotateAmount
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", animate )

local buttonHandler = function( event )
    if event.phase == "release" then
        if event.id == "stop" then
            rotateAmount = 0
        elseif event.id == "+1" then
            rotateAmount = rotateAmount + 1
        elseif event.id == "-1" then
            rotateAmount = rotateAmount - 1
        elseif event.id == "reverse" then
            rotateAmount = rotateAmount * -1
        end
    end
end

local button1 = ui.newButton{
    default = "button.png",
    over = "buttonOver.png",
    onEvent = buttonHandler,
    text = "Stop",
    id = "stop",
    size = 12,
    emboss = true
}
```

Comment: The error is in **ui.lua** at line #130

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old library. You should use new Corona widgets.

```
local widget = require( "widget" )

local myButton = widget.newButton
{
   left = 10,
   top = 80,
   label = "Default",
   labelAlign = "center",
   font = "Arial",
   fontSize = 18,
   labelColor = { default = {0,0,0}, over = {255,255,255} },
   onEvent = onButtonEvent
}
```

More info: http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2013/02/26/new-widgets-part-2/